# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting a substring of a string to a char element of a vector (C++)

Tags: c++, string, vector, exc-bad-access

I am trying to make a vector extended header. One of the functions sets a vector to the console input (cin). It uses the following code:

```
vector<char> cveccin(){
    string cinval;
    cin>>cinval;
    vector<char> creader;
    for (int i=0; i<cinval.size(); i++) {
        creader[i]=cinval[i];
    }
    return creader;
}
```

I use this function in a test, and it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your vector is size zero, and using [] won't make it any bigger.

There's a one-liner that does what you want.

```
vector<char> cveccin()
{
    string cinval;
    cin >> cinval;
    return vector<char>(cinval.begin(), cinval.end());
}
```

That code creates the vector of the right size, copies the cinval string to it, and returns it from the function, all in one line. Ain't C++ marvellous!

Comment: Thanks! I used your answer because it was simplest, but all the other answers worked too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add elements to std::vector use

```
vector<char> creader;
creader.push_back( var );
```

To use array notation you will have to first set the size of the std::vector

```
vector<char> creader;
creader.resize ( 10 );
creader[0] = var1;
creader[1] = var2;
```

Comment: Thanks to you to! All of your answers were great and would've worked (I think) but I used john's because it was the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the creader-vector you have created is empty. Because it holds no elements, you cannot access nor index any. To fix the problem, you could for example use the push_back method instead of indexing and assigning.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I didn't use that way because john's answer was really simple.